# Audio Track for playback in android

Tags: android, audiotrack

Audio track allows streaming PCM audio buffers to the audio hardware for playback. This is achieved by "pushing" the data to the Audio Track object using one of the `write(byte[], int, int)` and `write(short[], int, int)` methods.

PCM is Pulse code modulation is it that PCM that modulate analog voice to digital during Phone calls?and which list of hardware to playback? only speaker or some more? Can PCM allow to play audio on GSM network?

Answer (score 0):

> PCM is Pulse code modulation is it that PCM that modulate analog voice to digital during Phone calls?

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but typically there will be a piece of hardware in the phone called a *codec*. The codec controls the internal loudspeaker, earpiece, microphones, etc - and this is where the analogue audio singals will be sampled into digital audio streams (typically 48 kHz linear PCM).

What happens to the audio after that varies a bit between different platforms. It might for example be passed to an audio DSP (Digital Signal Processor) which applies various filters (e.g. noise suppression); and from there to the modem which takes care of compressing the audio (typically using AMR) and transmitting it to the network.

---

> and which list of hardware to playback? only speaker or some more??

Any device that the phone can route audio to. A phone will typically have an earpiece, one or more loudspeakers, a 3.5mm stereo jack, and a Bluetooth chip capable of both voice (SCO) and media (A2DP) audio. Some phones also support audio playback over USB and WiFi.
 Applications don't have direct control of the routing, though. The best you can do is give a hint to the OS about where you'd *like* the audio to be routed.

---

> Can PCM allow to play audio on GSM network??

No. This has nothing to do with the encoding of the audio. There simply isn't any API in Android for injecting audio into the uplink of a voice call.